# Devstack installation failed with error message "ERROR: Editable requirements are not allowed as constraints"

Tags: installation, openstack, devstack

I encounter the following error when I run the script stack.sh:

```
Using python 3.6 to install setuptools!=24.0.0,!=34.0.0,!=34.0.1,!=34.0.2,!=34.0.3,!=34.1.0,!=34.1.1,!=34.2.0,!=34.3.0,!=34.3.1,!=34.3.2,!=36.2.0,!=48.0.0,!=49.0.0
+ inc/python:pip_install:187               :   sudo -H LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS= SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite python3.6 -m pip install -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt --ignore-installed 'setuptools!=24.0.0,!=34.0.0,!=34.0.1,!=34.0.2,!=34.0.3,!=34.1.0,!=34.1.1,!=34.2.0,!=34.3.0,!=34.3.1,!=34.3.2,!=36.2.0,!=48.0.0,!=49.0.0'
DEPRECATION: Constraints are only allowed to take the form of a package name and a version specifier. Other forms were originally permitted as an accident of the implementation, but were undocumented. The new implementation of the resolver no longer supports these forms. A possible replacement is replacing the constraint with a requirement.. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8210.
ERROR: Editable requirements are not allowed as constraints
++./stack.sh:main:752                       err_trap
++./stack.sh:err_trap:530                   local r=1
stack.sh failed: full log in /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log.2021-05-10-115040
Error on exit
```

And a little higher I have this warning:

```
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.1
Successfully installed pip-21.1.1
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You
should install packages reliably by using venv:
https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Idin, the `err_trap` function can capture any error. Can you add what is above the first snippet you posted? That may contain the action leading up to the error. The error message itself does not ring a bell with me.

Comment: I have edited my question with more informations

Comment: What is the OS and version you are trying to install this on?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: That is the supported version of Ubuntu. If it is a clean install and you pulled the most recent changes of Devstack, I would not know where to start.